# Defining id ( @+id ) in constraint part of ConstraintLayout error

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

when first defining id ( @+id ) in constraint part ( such as `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` ) i get the error "cannot resolve symbol"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

see the screen shot:

[image]

In gradle I have constraint layout 1.1.3 and Android studio version is 3.2.1 I recently updated it from older version:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

app runs correctly without any error but the error is shown in android studio layout window.

Invalidating caches, rebuilding, and changing constraint layout version NONE of them helps!

In Java class `R.id.tv2` works correctly and when i control+click it I can see its field in `R` class. **editor is using another class for ids that is not same as the R class in java code?**

---

**This question was about a bug in old Android Studio and `ConstraintLayout` versions in current versions of Android Studio using `androidx` library this bug is not presented.**

Comment: Try swapping the values for `@+id/tv2` and `@id/tv2`. Put the one with `+` to the `TextView` below.

Comment: @Xenolion the first appearance of an id should has @+ not the second

Comment: @Xenolion i swap it now second textview is green but first one is still red and error

Comment: Ooooh that's weird but I am also starting to doubt your Android Studio.

Comment: @Xenolion this project target sdk is 27 i update android studio and change gradle plugin to 3.2.1 then i have to change build tools from 27.0.3 to 28.0.3 is there any error ?

Comment: I copy/paste your layout in my android studio and it worked without problem. with android studio 3.1.2, constaintLayout 1.1.0, support library 27.1.1

Comment: @Afshin with your version of android studio and constraint layout previously i also had no problem. but after updating android studio i get this error. this project target sdk is 27 i update android studio and change gradle plugin to 3.2.1 then i have to change build tools from 27.0.3 to 28.0.3 i also update constraint layout version

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question was about a bug in old Android Studio and `ConstraintLayout` versions in current versions of Android Studio using `androidx` library this bug is not presented.

Answer (score 2):

The plus sign `+`  is added when defining the id `(@+id/tv2)` but when referencing you don't need to add the plus sign like this `@id/tv2`.

Instead of this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To get it right I suggest you convert your code to Androidx.

The below code is written in Androidx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSI9Q.png)

Comment: The position where you must add + sign is the first line where you see id name so in this code because `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv2"` is above `android:id="@id/tv2"` the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv2"` should have plus sign.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the other answers, use `@+id/<your_name>` to declare new resources.

In my case, Android Studio **complained when using the `-` character** in names (even though the app compiled and worked either way).